# Qt: Drag and Drop inside a QListWidget does not work

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I've reimplemented a QListWidget in order to accept file drops. I just want to use the drag and drop to create a list of files.

Here is my .cpp implementation for it:

```
#include "dropenabledlistwidget.h"

DropEnabledListWidget::DropEnabledListWidget(QWidget *parent):QListWidget(parent)
{
    this->setAcceptDrops(true);
    ///this->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
    qDebug() << "Aca toy";
}


void DropEnabledListWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *e)
{
    if (e->mimeData()->hasUrls()) {
        e->acceptProposedAction();
    }
}


void DropEnabledListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event){
    qDebug() << "Drop Event";
    if (event->mimeData()->hasUrls()){
        QList<QUrl> urls = event->mimeData()->urls();
        for (qint32 i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++){
            qDebug() << urls.at(i).path();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to drag an item into it, I get the little red circle with a slash as cursor and nothing happens. But from the examples I've seen I'm doing everything I should.

Any Ideas?